# Compare EditText Value with String

Tags: android, android-edittext

I just wanna compare value of EditText, and want to show Toast according to case, in my program i simply want if edittext value equals to abc or ABC then show done in Toast else need to show error, and for that i have written few lines of easy code, but don't why its always showing error, even i have entered correct value (i.e:- ABC or abc)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText editTextInput;
String strInput;
Button btnInput;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editInput);
        strInput = editTextInput.getText().toString();

        btnInput = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnInput.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(strInput.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Get the `EditText` **text** inside `ClickListener` like below

```
btnInput.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            strInput = editTextInput.getText().toString();
```

**EDIT**

Initialize it with empty like below

```
String strInput = "";
```

and `Button` click add like below append it

```
strInput = strInput+","+editTextInput.getText().toString();
```

and set the **strInput** into `TextView` like below

```
textViewResult.setText(strInput);
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
btnInput.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
             String check = editTextInput.getText().toString();

              if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC"))
              {
                        strInput = strInput+","+check;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        textViewResult.setText(strInput);
                        editTextInput.setText("");
              }
              else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    
              }
       }
});
```

Comment: thanks my silly mistake, i ticked as useful and will accept your answer in next 11 minutes ... thanks :)

Comment: accepted but don't know why some one has downvoted this question, i tried my best

Comment: i am facing a small issue, will you help me, may i ask you ?

Comment: don't know why its showing error, whenever i do tap on button, check my updated code here: http://pastebin.com/Zjj82YF1

Comment: thanks for support and it's almost done but not 100% satisfactory solution, because whenever i open my app again it shows me last entered text into textview because i am using SharedPreference to save but now when i click on button again after putting text it removes last entered data from textview, why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55247/discussion-between-sophie-and-hariharan).

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096173/on-button-click-deletes-existing-data-from-textview-after-re-launching

Answer (score 1):

Just get the value of `EditText` inside `ClickListener`.

Try like below-

```
btnInput.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        strInput = editTextInput.getText().toString();
        if(strInput.equals("ABC")||strInput.equals("abc"))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         else 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Sophie Ok..But Thank you for ticking as useful .
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (editTextInput.getText().toString().equals("ABC"))
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is check when you add text in edit text

> EditText input = new EditText(context);
>
> input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
>   {
>   @Override
>         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
>               if((input.getText().toString()).equal(comprator)) 
>                   {
>                   showToast();
>                    }
>   }
>    @Override
>   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int b, int c) {
>
> ```
>        }
> ```
>
> public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st,int c, int a) {
>
> ```
>                   }
>               });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using equalsIgnoreCase method, will reduce one OR condition as per @priyanka's answer.

```
 btnInput.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            strInput = editTextInput.getText().toString();
            if(strInput.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC"))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             else 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
            }
        });
```